# Sharing categories between Woocommerce Products and a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, product, taxonomy

I need to assign some **Custom Post Types** and some **Woocommerce Products** to the same Category in a Wordpress installation.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does it have to be "category"? That may get a little confusing. You might consider registering a custom taxonomy to 'product' and your custom post type.

Comment: Yes, thank you, solved this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I created a *custom taxonomy* with **CPT UI** and assigned **both to my CPT and to my** **Woocommerce Products**.

This way I'm able to do a **WP_Query** using *'tax_query' => $myCustomTax* in my *$args* and filter both post types.